# Is function-like macro argument name substitution guaranteed to never happen?

Tags: c++, c

Consider the following code

```
#define foo 38
#define F(foo) G(foo)
F(42);
```

I expect this code to fail to compile because after applying the first line second line should transform into `#define F(38) G(38)` which does not make any sense. But on g++ it successfully compiles into `G(42)`, as if there was no first line at all. I was unable to find any mention of this behaviour in neither g++ docs nor c standard. I know that code is ugly and should not be used in the first place, but I wonder if it has any guarantees to be portable.

Comment: Pretty similar to [this example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html) no?

Comment: `F(42)` is converted by the preprocessor to the text `G(42)`.     The fact that the name of `F`s argument is the same as a previous macro (`foo`) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.10 7 and C++ 2017 (draft n4659) 19 [cpp] 6 both say:

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.

For parameters of function-like macros, nothing is otherwise stated. Therefore, the parameter names in the definition of a function-like macro are not replaced due to prior macro definitions.

(Examples of where macro expansion is otherwise stated include `#if` directives and `#include` directives.)